# Is there a way to change the formatting of a New DateTime (VB.NET, Access)

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, datetime, ms-access

I am utilizing an Access database to store recorded data. Currently, I am returning 0, but I know for the variable in the sub below there are approximately five occurrences. I am using the sub below to return the count of the occurrences of certain records in a certain month:

```
Public Sub CountAddedDIM() Handles MyBase.Load
        '***EDIT THESE DATES, DIFFERENT FORMATTING POSSIBLE?***
        Dim logDates() As DateTime = {New DateTime(1, 1, 2021),
                                      New DateTime(2, 1, 2021),
                                      New DateTime(3, 1, 2021),
                                      New DateTime(4, 1, 2021),
                                      New DateTime(5, 1, 2021),
                                      New DateTime(6, 1, 2021),
                                      New DateTime(7, 1, 2021),
                                      New DateTime(8, 1, 2021),
                                      New DateTime(9, 1, 2021),
                                      New DateTime(10, 1, 2021),
                                      New DateTime(11, 1, 2021),
                                      New DateTime(12, 1, 2021)}

        ' set 0,0
        PrintsAndShopCHRT.Series("Added Missing Dimension").Points.AddXY(0, 0)

        Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.accdb")
            connection.Open()

            For counter As Integer = 0 To logDates.Count - 1
                Dim sql = $"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DataCollection WHERE [ADDED MISSING DIMENSION] = 'Added Missing Dimension' AND [M/Y OF LOG] = @MY_OF_LOG;"
                Using Command As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
                    Command.Parameters.Add("@MY_OF_LOG", OleDbType.Date).Value = logDates(counter)
                    Dim returnValue = Command.ExecuteScalar()

                    Dim count As Integer = Integer.Parse(returnValue.ToString)

                    ' other points
                    PrintsAndShopCHRT.Series("Added Missing Dimension").Points.AddXY(counter + 1, count)
                End Using
            Next
        End Using

        ' INSERT CHART SETTINGS
        PrintsAndShopCHRT.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = 0.0
        PrintsAndShopCHRT.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = 12
        PrintsAndShopCHRT.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1
        PrintsAndShopCHRT.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Minimum = 0.0
        PrintsAndShopCHRT.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum = 45
        PrintsAndShopCHRT.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Interval = 5
    End Sub
```

When using the New Datetime formatting as I did, I get this error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Year, Month, and Day parameters
> describe an un-representable DateTime.'

I understand that DateTimes are normally formatted as "YYYY, MM, dd", but is there any way it could be formatted like the sub above shows? My database column that uses the month/day/year information uses the formatting mm/dd/yyyy.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You aren't passing formatted date/times; you're passing separate values for month, day, and year. Once you've separated the date-string into separate month, day, and year values, you pass them as the constructor for a DateTime expects, or you write your own function to take them in your preferred order. Alternatively, build your DateTime using the [`DateTime.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-5.0) or [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0) methods.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin "You aren't passing formatted date/times;" I can't see where this is happening. What is passed is an element of a DateTime array.

Comment: No, there is no January with 2021 days. All you need to do is think (yyyy, MM, dd) when you are *typing* the new datetime.

Comment: I notice the database column name is `[M/Y OF LOG]` - does that mean it is a ***text representation** of the month and year*?

Comment: @Mary - the code is _not_ doing that; the way the question is asked implied that the querent seems to think that the format of the date as a string matters, and he wants the constructor to conform to the order that the formatted date uses. This is a classic example of confusion of data values with their representations.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for DateTime has many overloads. The one you apparently are using is year, month, day.  See

[DateTime constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a extension method.

```
Module DateTimeCustomFormatExtensions
<Extension()>
Function ToCustomFormat(ByVal dt As DateTime) As DateTime
    Dim culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
    Return DateTime.ParseExact(dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), "MM/dd/yyyy", culture)
End Function
End Module
```

The code looks like:

```
Dim logDates() As DateTime = {New DateTime(2021, 1, 1).ToCustomFormat(),
                                  New DateTime(2021, 2, 1).ToCustomFormat(),
                                  ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see if you followed @dbasnett link. The constructor for a `DataTime` takes `(year, month, day)`. You put the year in the day slot so of course it was out or range for a day that should be 1 - 31.

I also wanted to point out that you should create the command and the parameters  collection once, outside the loop. The only thing that changes is the value of the parameter inside the `For` loop. You don't need to `.Parse` the returned value. We know that `Count` always returns an `Integer` (except MySql where it returns a `Long`) so we can just convert it with `CInt`.

The only reason I used a list of `DataPoint` is I wasn't sure how to manipulate the `Series` in a `For` loop. I wanted to show what was returned. `.AddXY` can take an array of `DataPoint`. If you get an error here just change to

```
Chart1.Series("Added Missing Dimension").Points.AddXY(ChartPoints.ToArray)
```

Code not tested.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim logDates() As DateTime = {New DateTime(2021, 1, 1),
                                  New DateTime(2021, 2, 1),
                                  New DateTime(2021, 3, 1),
                                  New DateTime(2021, 4, 1),
                                  New DateTime(2021, 5, 1),
                                  New DateTime(2021, 6, 1),
                                  New DateTime(2021, 7, 1),
                                  New DateTime(2021, 8, 1),
                                  New DateTime(2021, 9, 1),
                                  New DateTime(2021, 10, 1),
                                  New DateTime(2021, 11, 1),
                                  New DateTime(2021, 12, 1)}
    Dim sql = $"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DataCollection WHERE [ADDED MISSING DIMENSION] = 'Added Missing Dimension' AND [M/Y OF LOG] = @MY_OF_LOG;"
    Dim ChartPoints As New List(Of DataPoint)
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.accdb"),
            Command As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
        Command.Parameters.Add("@MY_OF_LOG", OleDbType.Date)
        connection.Open()
        For counter As Integer = 0 To logDates.Count - 1
            Command.Parameters("@MY_OF_LOG").Value = logDates(counter)
            Dim count = CInt(Command.ExecuteScalar())
            ChartPoints.Add(New DataPoint(counter + 1, count))
        Next
    End Using
    'To see if you are getting the data you expect
    For Each p As DataPoint In ChartPoints
        Debug.Print($"{p.XValue}, {p.YValues}")
    Next
    Chart1.Series("Added Missing Dimension").Points.AddXY(ChartPoints)
End Sub
```